# Execute a php page in background from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have this `tab.php` page that is basically the index of the site. It contains all JavaScript and HTML code.

I'm trying to send some array from this page to a PHP page and than do an update query, uploading the array on my phpmyadmin.

I used this code in `tab.php` but it doesn't work.

```
 var send_array = {
"red": redtruppe,
"blue": bluetruppe,
"orange": orangetruppe,
"purple": purpletruppe,
"black": blacktruppe,
"green": greentruppe
};

$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "send.php", 
   data: { TruppeJson : send_array }, 
   success: function() { 
          alert("Success"); 
    } 
});
```

the send.php page is, for now, something like this:

```
<?php
$myTruppe = json_decode($_POST['TruppeJson']);
echo '<script>console.log('.$myTruppe.')</script>';
?>
```

The success alert seems to work, but the `send.php` apparently not, any suggestions?

Comment: in what way is `send.php` failing? the `<script>console.log.....etc` will be the data returned by  the POST request ... if you have `success: function(result) { alert(result); }` you'll see that text alerted, i.e. it will alert `<script>console.log('... the json will be here ...')</script>` - probably not what you expected, but that's whatyou wrote

Comment: First of all thanks for answering, i tried to use "success: function(result) { alert(result); }" and changing the echo but, my json file seems to be empty

Comment: there is no json file

Comment: Sorry I mean the array

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that for the data:

```
 JSON.stringify(send_array)
```

and define your dataType as JSON

```
dataType: "json"
```

Would look like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "send.php", 
   data: JSON.stringify(send_array),
   dataType: "json",
   success: function() { 
          alert("Success"); 
    } 
});
```

As you stated, success is getting called. So your data is not just been sent to the backend.

Comment: Thanks, i tried but now success is not getting called